# how to call activity class in onCreateView of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have code like this

```
public class fragment2 extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, container, false);
}
```

}

i want to call activity class instead of layout.
please help me.

Comment: please explain what are you trying to achieve by calling the activity class?

Comment: my activity class contain a url to load so if i call layout then it will not load url. so i want to start the activity class to load url.

Comment: why do you want to call activity class? Any specific reason.

Comment: why are you using the fragment? what do you mean by load URL? do you want to load it on web view?

Comment: in my application i am parsing some data by using json parser.it will do not parse data if i call layout directly.So i want to call the activity class.

Comment: I am assuming that you are parsing some json data and then using it for creating your UI? why don't you move the parsing code to the fragment? Again I am assuming that parsed data is only required in the fragment class..

Comment: @ Praful Bhatnagar. Thank's a lot it work's...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388170/how-to-handle-back-button-when-we-call-facebook-or-twitter-from-the-fragment-cla @PrafulBhatnagar please give answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Following link talks about communication between two fragment via activity..

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

same example can be used to communicate back to the activity from fragment.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have activity and fragment called MyActivity and MyFragment,
you can provide some public method in MyActivity. After this in the MyFragment#onCreateView()
you can call
 `String layout = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getMyLayoutLink()`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface in the fragment, then implement it in the activity. You then set the listener in the fragments onAttach() method. This is called before onCreateView(). This pattern makes your code reusable and this technique can apply for all your activities and fragments they use. Example code for the fragment:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnItemSelectedListener onClickListener;

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
      //implement and use this function in your calling activity
      public void yourItemSelected(String link);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      //check that the activity implements the interface
      if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
        //set the listener to the calling activity
        onClickListener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
      } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
        + " must implement YourFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
      }
    }

}
```

For more info see the android documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle